# How do I add collision detection to the sides of the window in Tkinter? [Python 3]

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection, python-3.4, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a simple game in Tkinter, and I'm working on the basic movement. It works well except for the fact that the player can move off the screen.

How would I add collision detection to the sides of the window?

I'm moving the player with a `move` function bound to the arrow keys, like this:

```
def move(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -5)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, 5)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        self.canvas.move(self.id, -5, 0)
    else:
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 5, 0)
```

Comment: What do you want to detect the collision of, the cursor ? Or an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size of your canvas like this:

```
size, _ = self.canvas.winfo_geometry().split('+', maxsplit=1)
w, h = (int(_) for _ in size.split('x'))
```

And the position of your `Squarey` like this:

```
x, y, _, __ = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
```

(There may be better ways to do this, of course)

Then just adapt your movement function like this:

```
if event.keysym == 'Up':
    if y > 0:
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -5)
elif event.keysym == 'Down':
    if y+50 < h:
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, 5)
elif event.keysym == 'Left':
    if x > 0:
        self.canvas.move(self.id, -5, 0)
else:
    if x+50 < w:
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 5, 0)
```

That should work for you (at least it does for me). But you shouldn't stop here, there are some improvements that you can make.

The first one that I would do is something like this:

```
def __init__(self, canvas, color, width=50, height=50):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, width, height, fill=color)
```

Then you could change your move:

```
left_edge = x
right_edge = left_edge + self.width
top_edge = y
bottom_edge = top_edge + self.height

if event.keysym == 'Up' and top_edge > 0:
    ...
elif event.keysym == 'Down' and bottom_edge < h:
    ...
elif event.keysym == 'Left' and left_edge > 0:
    ...
elif event.keysym == 'Right' and right_edge < w:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to detect the collision of a rectangle with the edges of the screen. I am stranger to tkinter, however I have experience with pygame, let me explain as well as I can.

In pygame, a rectange position are given as left_top corner, a(one side), b(another side). Such as,

```
(x, y)    b
   ...............
   .             .
   .             .
  a.             .
   .             .
   ...............
```

if you want to detect collision, you have to check all sides, using these values.

Let's say screen is `(width, height)`

```
# Top side collision
if y < 0:
    print "Touched top"
# Right side collision
if x + b > width:
    print "Touched right"
# Bottom side collision
if y + a > height:
    print "Touched bottom"
# Left side collision
if x < 0:
    print "Touched left"
```

I am pretty sure quite similar logic is needed in tkinter as well.